# Is there a subgroup of dual depth 3?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, subfactors, gap

This post is motivated by an exchange with Zhengwei Liu.  It is more than the dual version of [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/312116/34538), because we consider any subgroup (instead of just *maximal*), and even more at the end...

Let's first define what we mean by *dual depth of a subgroup* (coming from [this book](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/abstract-analysis/introduction-subfactors) p141).

Let $G$ be a finite group, and $H$ a subgroup. The double cosets $HgH$ form a partition of $G$. Let $R_H \subset G$ be a subset of representatives for these double cosets, i.e. 
$$ G=\coprod_{g \in R_H} HgH. $$
Now, let $K_g \subset H$ be the subgroup $H \cap gHg^{-1}$, for $g \in R_H$.
Consider the bipartite graph $\mathcal{G}$ whose odd vertices are (up to isom.) the irreducible complex representations (irreps) $V$ of $H$, and the even vertices are the irreps $W$ of $K_g$ with $g \in R_H$, and with $d$ edges between $V$ and $W$ if $\langle V\vert_{K_g},W \rangle = d$. Let $*$ be the even vertex which is the trivial representation of $K_{e} = H$. Let $\mathcal{G}_0$ be the connected component of $\mathcal{G}$ containing $*$, it will be called the dual principal graph. Note that $\Vert \mathcal{G}_0 \Vert^2 = |G:H|$.

**Definition**: The *dual depth* of $H⊂G$ is the distance between $*$ and a farthest vertex in $\mathcal{G}_0$.

Note that the dual depth of $H⊂G$ is $2$ if and only if $H$ is a normal subgroup. Moreover, the dual principal graph (and so the dual depth) is invariant if we quotient by the core of $H$ in $G$, so that we can assume $H$ [core-free](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Core-free_subgroup).

The dual principal graph for $\{e\} \subset C_3$ (index $3$, dual depth $2$):
[image]
In general, the dual principal graph of $\{e\} \subset G$ is just a star with $|G|$ arms of length one.

The dual principal graph of $\langle (1,2)(3,4) \rangle \subset A_4$ (index $6$, dual depth $4$):
[image]

The dual principal graph for $A_4 \subset A_5$ (index $5$, dual depth $6$):
[image]

We computed (with the code below) the dual depth of every core-free proper subgroup $H \subset G$ in the following cases:

- $|G:H|<32$ and $|G|<10^4$,
- $H$ maximal, $|G:H|<100$ and $|G|<10^6$,
- $G$ simple, $H$ maximal, and $|G|<2\cdot 10^6$.

Surprisingly, we found no one with a dual depth $3$. In fact, we found no one with an odd dual depth.

*Question 1*: Is there a subgroup of dual depth $3$?

If no:
*Question 2*: Is there a proper subgroup of odd dual depth?

If yes (to Question 2):
*Question 3*: Is there a maximal subgroup of odd dual depth?

---

**Code**

```
PrincipalGraph:=function(G,H)
    local mat,edges;
    mat:=MatScalarProducts(Irr(H),RestrictedClassFunctions(Irr(G),H)); #Print(mat);
    edges := Filtered( Cartesian([1..Size(mat)],-[1..Size(mat[1])]), ij -> not IsZero(mat[ij[1]][-ij[2]]));
    return edges;
end;;

DualPrincipalGraph:=function(G,H)
    local dc,l,rep,grp,g,L,K,ed,edd,n,edges;
    dc:=DoubleCosetRepsAndSizes(G,H,H);
    rep:=List(dc,l->l[1]);
    grp:=List(rep,g->Intersection(H,ConjugateGroup(H,g)));
    L:=List(grp,K->PrincipalGraph(H,K));
    edges:=[];
    n:=0;
    for ed in L do
        edd:=List(ed,l->[l[1],l[2]-n]);
        Append(edges,edd);
        n:=n+Length(Set(List(ed,l->l[2])));
    od;
    edges:=List(edges,l->[-l[2],-l[1]]);
    return edges;
end;;  

DepthGraph:=function(Gr)
    local P,dd,c,cc,PP,a;
    P:=Gr;
    dd:=0;
    c:=[1];
    while P<>[] do
        PP:=[];
        cc:=[];
        for a in P do
            if a[1] in c then
                Add(cc,a[2]);
            elif a[2] in c then
                Add(cc,a[1]);
            else 
                Add(PP,a);
            fi;
        od;
        c:=cc;
        P:=PP;
        dd:=dd+1;
    od;
    return dd;
end;;   

DepthDualSubgroup:=function(G,H)
    local Gr;
    Gr:=DualPrincipalGraph(G,H);
    return DepthGraph(Gr);
end;;

DepthDualTransitive:=function(d,r)
    local G,H,dd;
    G:=TransitiveGroup(d,r);
    H:=Stabilizer(G,1);
    dd:=DepthDualSubgroup(G,H);
    return dd;
end;;

DepthDualPrimitive:=function(d,r)
    local G,H,dd;
    G:=PrimitiveGroup(d,r);
    H:=Stabilizer(G,1);
    dd:=DepthDualSubgroup(G,H);
    return dd;
end;;  

DualDepthOddMaxSubSimple:=function(n,m)
    local it,i,G,T,M,x,H,l,L,d;
    it:=SimpleGroupsIterator(n,m);
    l:=[]; L:=[];
    for i in it do
        Add(l,i);
    od;
    for G in l do
        M:=MaximalSubgroupClassReps(G);
        for H in M do
            d:=DepthDualSubgroup(G,H);
            Add(L,d);
            if d mod 2 = 1 then
                Print([d,G,H,IdGroup(H)]); #Add(L,Order(G)/Order(H));
            fi;
        od;
    od;
    L:=List(Set(L));
    return L;
end;;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. More generally:

**Proposition**: There is no proper subgroup of odd dual depth.

*Proof*: Let $H \subset G$ be a proper (core-free) subgroup. Let $v$ be a farthest odd vertex from the vertex $*$ in the graph $\mathcal{G}_0$. The vertex $v$ is given by a non-trivial irrep $V$ of $H$. But $K_e = H$, so there is also an even vertex $v'$ given by the irrep $V$ for $K_e$, but $v'$ is of valency $1$ (the only edge that connects to it is $[v,v']$). So $v'$ is farther from $*$ than $v$, i.e. the dual depth of $H \subset G$ is even. $\square$

*Remark*: The proof works as well if we replace the two occurrences of $K_e$ by $K_g$ with $g \in R_H$ such that $Hg=gH$. Let $m$ be the number of such $K_g$ ($m>0$ because $g=e$ works).

Note that there are exactly $m$ vertices of valency $1$ and at distance $1$ from the depth $1$ vertex, they are given by the trivial irrep for the above $K_g$.

Assume that the dual depth of $H \subset G$ is $d \ge 4$.
Let $n>0$ be the number of vertices at depth $d-1$ in the graph.

*Consequence*:   There are at least $nm$ vertices at depth $d$. More precisely, from each irrep $V$ of $H$ at depth $d-1$ starts (among possible others) $m$ edges going to the depth $d$ vertices of the irrep $V$ for the $m$ different $K_g$ equals to $H$.

[image]

Comment: Why can't $v'$ be at the previous depth instead of the next depth?

Comment: @NoahSnyder: if $v$ is at depth $d$ and $v'$ at depth $d-1$ then there must have a third vertex $v''$ at depth $d-2$ related to $v'$, i.e. $$v'' - v' - v$$ but there is one and only one edge starting from $v'$, contradiction. Conclusion, $v'$ is at depth $d+1$.

Comment: Ah sorry, I see.